# Newest Flutter 2.0 caused my App to have 32 errors. Before update I had none

Tags: flutter, dart

I am very new to flutter haven't even finished my Udmey course yet. I was working on a project and saw that Flutter 2.0 had been released and So I thought to update to that. Before the update, my app was working 100 per cent and then after update, I now have 32 errors. Some are core feature I learned to use for example:

```
onSaved: (newValue) {
                       _userEmail = newValue;
         },
```

newValue no longer works. The error is

```
A value of type 'String?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'String'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'String'
```

Or

```
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value.isEmpty || !value.contains('@')) {
                          return 'Please enter valid email';
                        }
```

!value is erroring out :

```
The method 'contains' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.
Try making the call conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!')
```

Plus many more. What must I do now?

Comment: You should watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bvq7wbn4VAA

Comment: Unless you deliberately updated your pubspec to have a minimum sdk version >= 2.12.0, you should have experienced almost no change.  Other people's comments are about already making the jump to 2.12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah these are all the issues related to null safety feature, follow the below guide to resolve them.

https://dart.dev/null-safety/migration-guide

Answer (score 2):

you can see all of the fixes  to make across your entire project:

```
$ dart fix --dry-run
```

If you’d like to apply them in bulk, you can easily do so:

```
$ dart fix --apply
```

Comment: I tried that and it said there are no errors. So not sure what to do there